# I want to help and answer questions, but I can't find questions to answer

Tags: support

I am a programmer with an intermediate skill level and still do not have the skills to solve many of the problems asked on Stack Overflow. There are a lot of questions however that I believe I could still answer. A lot of the questions I have asked I have viewed as those easy to solve kind of questions if you know what you are doing.

How do I find questions that I am able to answer with my knowledge?

I know some [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), JavaScript, [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), etc. However when I browse these tags I find myself struggling to find a question I can answer. And when I do find one I could answer there are already multiple answers.

Comment: Use the [advanced search](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to narrow down questions that are topics you have knowledge in, and are not answered. Older questions are also good starting locations.

Comment: Related: [How to find the right questions that I can answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer)

Comment: Use the recommended tab

Comment: Do not immediately skip questions that are already answered. *Read these answers*. All of them. Do you understand them? If you do, do you agree? If not, could they be improved? Don't hesitate to post a comment if something is unclear. If it's unclear to *you* it may be unclear to others as well. Most (in my experience, *by far*) answerers are happy to expand on their answer when asked.

Comment: As an example of the above, see [my naive question on loops in MatLab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107361/convert-digit-to-vector-octave-matlab#comment39072012_25107361) (me knowing absolutely nothing about MatLab) and the very courteous and illuminating answer. I learned something new today.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if when asking a new question, you MUST choose a **difficulty level**.

Comment: @Joiner I thought of suggesting that however it seems very arbitrary what is considered harder and what isn't. When I'm asking a question it is probably hard for me to solve but I don't know whether or not it is hard to others.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the the **Favorite Tags** edit link to select tags where you have special interest or knowledge for. The questions coming up in the general stream, tagged with one or more of your favorite tags, will be highlighted for your settings accordingly.

Also if you simply click on one of these favorite tags, this will narrow the questions stream accordingly. That's the way I mostly work with it, and get back to my main stream of current interest from viewing questions.

Last but not least, you can of course combine several tags by entering e.g. `[c++][singleton]` in the search field. But as this gets you to more specific questions, getting back there from viewing them is harder (you'll have to go back to the search field explicitly again).

Workflow sketch:

1. Select questions filtered by a tag of current interest
2. View new questions (you'll be notified about new questions available)
3. Apply action on the viewed question (comment, answer, up-/downvote, flag, close-vote, etc.)
   3.1 No tags were edited, go back to the main stream of interest just by clicking the questions appropriate tag
   3.2 The main tag of interest was removed =>

   - Go back to the main stream via [Questions] tab
   - Click the main tag of interest from your favourites section

Comment: You can also use "intags:mine" as a search term to find all questions that have one of your favorite tags.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Ah THX! I didn't know this shortcut.

Comment: But in a lot of popular tags this still does not help. Say I am in jquery tag. Thee are plenty of questions that I can't answer there.

Comment: @Fogest Note that you can also leave tags aside using the ``Ignored Tags** section, when you're editing your favorite tags.

Answer (score 2):

I also find it hard to answer a lot of questions these days. The easy ones were already asked long ago and now I tend to see very specific questions that require you to put in a lot of research to answer them.

In order to answer a decent amount of questions today you either need to have:

1. Advanced knowledge in a particular area
2. Be on Stack Overflow when its quieter
3. Be prepared to spend a lot more time researching someone's question. Don't just read and say I don't know. Think if you could spend 5-10 mins making a mock up of their code and seeing if you could solve it. Do that with questions that don't have any answers after an hour (roughly).

Comment: Totally agree with #3, but disagree with #1 (see my #1) and #2.

Answer (score 2):

Search filters are your friend.

For instance suppose you want to find these types of questions:

1. Cover one of your areas of expertise (for example PHP)
2. Have some upvotes, i.e are decent questions
3. Have no answers yet
4. Were created recently (say in the last two months)
5. Were not marked as duplicates

Then you can construct a search filter like this (at time of this post):

> [PHP]answers:0 score:1...5 created:2014-06 duplicate:no

This will return a list of questions with the PHP tag that were created recently,have some positive votes, and have not been marked as duplicates.

That helps narrow down the questions, and avoids problems like the Fastest Gun In The West and  the possibility of the question being downvoted/marked as  duplicate/etc, that may occur with brand new questions.

Of course that's just an example, your criteria may vary for what kinds of questions you want to search for.

The SO Help Center has more information about constructing search filters under [How do I Search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) You can tailor your filters to criteria that are most useful to you.

Comment: Great tips! I use `closed:no` too.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 ways you can go about answering those difficult questions right now:

1. Read the question thoroughly and break down the logic. For example, I've never looked at a Delphi tutorial in my life and [at the time of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527895/1031312), I had no experience of SQL either.
2. [Debug the problem yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548062/1031312), and find the answer (imo this is the best way to learn). I'm sure you've seen those jsfiddle answers?
3. [Research the topic first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113619/1031312), and then [share your knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422525/1031312)