# How do you find questions you are interested in?

Tags: support, questions

Actually I spend a lot of time while trying to find questions I can answer with my knowledge, so now I want to understand what is the real problem.

I already use Favorite Tags and I already browse by the programming language.

Sadly, I noticed that these questions are the ones asked by newbies (< 10 rep users).

So, how can I find this kind of questions quickly?

Comment: _"asked by newbies (< 10 rep users)"_ Well, that's an indication, but certainly not proves for a novice in the field being asked for. There are users with low rep, but reading for a long time, or that just have joined, but with a well reputational knowledge of what they're asking for. The most common problem (with any kind of new users) is, that they aren't asking well formed as stated in the policies of the SO site.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any **Favorite Tags** set already?
Questions containing one of your fav tags will be `highlighted` on the main incoming queues.
Also you may add **Ignored Tags** to have questions *lowlighted* at those queues.

Another technique is to work with a single tag or the `intags:mine` filter of your primary interest. See my [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268157/i-want-to-help-and-answer-questions-but-i-cant-find-questions-to-answer/268159#268159) for details.

Comment: I know. **I am not looking for answers like _"Use tags."_.**

Comment: @Joiner Then clarify your question please!

Comment: Now your answer has no sense. What should we do?

Comment: @Joiner If anything else fails for you, creating a [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) query with the criteria important for you might help. My answer makes still sense of course. Check the link, proposing a reasonable workflow.

Comment: Remove the Tags part and add an example query, then delete your comments.

Comment: @Joiner _"Remove the Tags part and add an example query ..."_ **Nope!** I use it rarely myself, and actually it's you seemingly needing it; play with it yourself please! 1st clearly state your requirements in your question, may be someone more versed with the SE data model could give you a good example. 2nd I still think my workflow proposal makes more sense for everyday's work, than using a query.